# I want to convert "20022017 131221" to datetime using C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I want to convert

> "20022017 160021"

To Date Time format in c#.net.

I tried the following code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20022017 160021", "DD/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What's the actual format you expect?

Comment: Try using `"ddMMyyyy HHmmss"` as the format.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the right function but with a wrong format.
This should work for you:

```
 DateTime.ParseExact("20022017 160021", "ddMMyyyy HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: It's again throwing an error "String was not recognized as valid date time"

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 DateTime.ParseExact("20022017 160021", "ddMMyyyy HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: That string format can't be correct - it's using `mm` twice. Even if I can't remember which way around the minutes/months specifiers are, I know that we don't use exactly the same symbols for both.